# Register new type of user in Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to make two types of users in laravel and I have two tables for that. I want to use defined register view and controller from laravel, but when I register new users it saved only in the first table.

The problem is with this `url('/register')` from here `<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/register') }}" id="form_reg1">`which I don't know how to edit this url for sending post request, because I'm using two forms, one for the first type of user, and one for the second type of user.

This is the first controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/index';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
            'first_name' => 'required|max:255',
            'last_name' => 'required|max:255',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
            'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

and this is second controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Merchant;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterMerchantController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/index';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
            'first_name' => 'required|max:255',
            'last_name' => 'required|max:255',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return Merchant::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
            'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

So any idea?

Comment: Can you post your `RegisterController` so we can help you better?

Comment: Place you route code here

Comment: @melanholly I edit the question

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd I don't have route code for this controller because laravel 5.3 had defined register and you dont have to make the route

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to approach this problem. One of them is to use a user type hidden field in the `register.blade.php` and based on the field to have login in your register controller to validate the input.

```
<input type="hidden" name="user_type" id="user_type" value="user">
```

You can use a select like

```
<select id="user_type" name="user_type">
  <option value="user">User</option>
  <option value="merchant">Merchant</option>
</select>
```

For example the `RegisterController`:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        'first_name' => 'required|max:255',
        'last_name' => 'required|max:255',
        'user_type' =>'required|in:user,merchant'
    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array $data
 * @return User|Merchant
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    if ($data['user_type'] == "merchant") {
        return Merchant::create([
            'name'       => $data['name'],
            'email'      => $data['email'],
            'password'   => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
            'last_name'  => $data['last_name'],
        ]);
    } else {
        return User::create([
            'name'       => $data['name'],
            'email'      => $data['email'],
            'password'   => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
            'last_name'  => $data['last_name'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> It would be better if you save users into a same table and use
>   **[polymorphic relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations)** to distinguish both of them. This technique
>   will also help you to *authenticate users* as you can authenticate users
>   by referencing to a single table (`users`).

So your table structures would be like this:

```
- users
    - id
    - owner_id
    - owner_type
    - email
    - password
    - token
    - ...

- clients
    - id
    - name
    - gender
    - mobile
    - ...

- merchants
    - id
    - name
    - gender
    - mobile
    - ...
```

Your Models - `Client`, `User` & `Merchant` would look like this:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function owner()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

class Client extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(User::class, 'owner');
    }
}

class Merchant extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->morphOne(User::class, 'owner');
    }
}
```

Now inside your HTML form, you can add a `select` option to select the type of user you want to create (or you can take the help of `hidden fields` to implement it), I am using a select option for the demonstration purpose:

```
<form action="{{ route('register_route_name') }}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <select name="type">
        <option disabled> Select Type of User </option>
        <option value="1"> Client </option>
        <option value="2"> Merchant </option>
    </select>

    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="text" name="mobile">

    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="0"> Male
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="1"> Female

    <input type="email" name="email">
    <input type="password" name="password">

    <input type="submit" value="Register">

</form>
```

Now inside your controller you'll add users according to the type you'll get from the for like this:

```
class RegisterController extends Controller
{

    public function register()
    {
        // You should use validator here to validate your inputs here...
        $inputs = request()->except('_token');

        if($inputs['type'] == 1) {
            $profile = Client::create(array_only($inputs, ['mobile, 'gender', 'name']));
        } else {
            $profile = Merchant::create(array_only($inputs, ['mobile, 'gender', 'name']));
        }

        $user_inputs_arr = array_only($inputs, ['email', 'password']);
        $user_inputs_arr['password'] = bcrypt($inputs['password']);

        $user = $profile->user()->create($user_inputs_arr);
        // Hence your client is registered successfully...
    }

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Why Client model is owner model, i think that User model should be owner?

Comment: According to my understanding, Client is a common model for both `User` and `Merchant`, its totally up to you, you can change it according to your feasibility, there's nothing hard and fast rules for this :D

Comment: No you didn't understand my question, I want to have two types of users, clients and merchants (clients and merchants to be two different tables), instead of having only one users table. So thats why I'm confused about you answer..

Comment: I think that you didn't understand me correctly, by the way I've updated the answer above according to your understanding. Now taking `users` as a common table...

Comment: I will try now and give you feedback later

Comment: I think you should change something in register controller and model functions

Comment: I've updated the code above, in `Client`, `Merchant` and `RegisterController`, please have a look.