# How to register more than one type of users and how to make multi auth in laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Maybe someone will notice that I'm asking this question again but I have reason for that. I have asked two questions before about this problem and I didn't find any good еxplanation and answer..

[How to make two types of users in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40766484/how-to-make-two-types-of-users-in-laravel)

[Register new type of user in Laravel 5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40974275/register-new-type-of-user-in-laravel-5-3)

I will try to explain better now what is my question in general. I'm trying to register two types of users, and my idea is to have two different tables for that users, and the second problem that I have is how to make multi authentication after I register the user `on one same login form`.

I'm searching for answers for long time and I didn't find any good answer.

Thank you very much!

Comment: you could leverage the Entrust package and just use user roles?

Comment: In my case i don't need user roles, I have make two different tables..

Comment: Also why do you need separate user tables? Can't you just use different user models?

Comment: Explaining your case would help people greatly

Comment: I need separate user tables because the columns will not be the same, the informations will be different..

Comment: u may watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lVxExcoFsTc&t=2s may be this is not the exact solution but u can modify or find a way

Answer (score 0):

You have to **override** the built-in authentication function in Laravel.

**NOTE: For laravel 5.3** : the functions are in `RegisterController.php` and you have to `php artisan make:auth` to create these controllers (refer to https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication).

**NOTE: For laravel 5.2 and lower** :
When you look at your `AuthController.php`, you will see it uses the trait `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers`. Try to look at all the functions in this trait in Laravel's vendor php files (...\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth...) and you can re-use (override) them in your `AuthController.php` by applying your desired changes to them.

In your case, you probably want to change 3 functions `register`,`validator` and `create`. So find these functions in the authentication controller and add your custom code.

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
    }

    //Add custom code here
    $new_user = $this->create($request->all());
    //Add custom code here

    Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->login($new_user);

    return redirect($this->redirectPath());
}

//Here you can differentiate the columns for each type of users...
protected function create(array $data)
{
  if ($data['user_type']=='Type1'){
    return UserType1::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'customInfoType1' => 'this is specific to User Type 1'
    ]);
  }else{
    return UserType2::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'customInfoType2' => 'this is specific to User Type 2'
    ]);
  }
}

//And don't forget to change the validator if the validation rules are different for each type
protected function validator(array $data)
{
  if ($data['user_type']=='Type1'){
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users_type1',
        'password' => 'required|min:6',
        'customInfoType1' => 'whatever validation rules'
    ]);
  }else{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users_type2',
        'password' => 'required|min:6',
        'customInfoType2' => 'whatever validation rules'
    ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: The new version Laravel 5.3 don't have AuthController, you are saying probably for some older version

Comment: In 5.3, these functions are in RegisterController.php. See my updated answer

Comment: Can you update the register function with that custom code because I didn't understand why I need that function

Comment: What you need to understand is that Laravel fires these functions through the conventional authentication routes (register and login). You need to override them with new ones. I show you here how to do it in Laravel 5.2, but I don't have the code for Laravel 5.3