# How to use authentication on custom model in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm making new custom model for user in laravel. I'm using the default `User` laravel model for one type of users that I will have, and new `Merchant` model for other type of users.

I make select option in the `register` view for chosing which type of user will be registered for better control in the controller.

```
<select id="user_type" name="user_type">
  <option value="user">User</option>
  <option value="merchant">Merchant</option>
</select>
```

This is my modified the default `RegisterController` for both type of users:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Merchant;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Auth;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/index';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $this->throwValidationException(
                $request, $validator
            );
        }

        //Add custom code here
        $new_user = $this->create($request->all());
        //Add custom code here

        Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->login($new_user);

        return redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        if($data['user_type']=='user'){
            return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
            'first_name' => 'required|max:255',
            'last_name' => 'required|max:255',
            'user_type' =>'required'
        ]);
        }else{
            return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
            'first_name' => 'required|max:255',
            'last_name' => 'required|max:255',
            'user_type' =>'required'
           ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        if($data['user_type']=='user'){
            return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
            'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
        ]);
       }else{
           return Merchant::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
            'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
        ]);
       }

    }

}
```

To mention that `register` function is not by default in `register controller`, so I put that function because I already view that solution [How to register more than one type of users and how to make multi auth in laravel 5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40978157/how-to-register-more-than-one-type-of-users-and-how-to-make-multi-auth-in-larave) but I don't know how to modify that.

But the problem now is with the authentication after I submit the registration form. If I register new `user` it's working fine, but if I register `merchant` it saved the user in database and after that it doesn't log in the merchant if it doesn't exist any `user` in the `users` table. But if it already exist any `user` in the `users` after I register the `merchant` it log in the last `user` which is created in `users` table.

So my question is how to modify the authentication for merchant user.

Thank you!

**UPDATE:**

Register function

```
public function register(Request $request)
    {
         if($request->user_type =='user'){
                $auth = auth()->guard();
            } else{
                $auth = auth()->guard('merchant');
            }

            $user = $this->create($request->all());
            auth()->login($user);

            return redirect($this->redirectPath());


    }
```

Comment: I update the question about that function

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Go to `/config/auth.php`
2. Find `guards` element of an array

   ```
   'guards' => [
       'web' => [
           'driver' => 'session',
           'provider' => 'users',
       ],

       'api' => [
           'driver' => 'passport',
           'provider' => 'users',
       ],
   ],
   ```
3. Add a guard `merchant` to this array with `provider` value of **`merchants`**

   ```
   'guards' => [
       'web' => [
           'driver' => 'session',
           'provider' => 'users',
       ],

       'api' => [
           'driver' => 'passport',
           'provider' => 'users',
       ],

       'merchant' => [
           'driver' => 'session',
           'provider' => 'merchants',
       ],
   ],
   ```
4. Now find `providers` element of this configuration

   ```
   'providers' => [
       'users' => [
           'driver' => 'eloquent',
           'model' => App\User::class,
       ],
   ],
   ```
5. Add `merchants` provider with `model` value of your `Merchant` model

   ```
   'providers' => [
       'users' => [
           'driver' => 'eloquent',
           'model' => App\User::class,
       ],

       'merchants' => [
           'driver' => 'eloquent',
           'model' => App\Merchant::class,
       ],
   ],
   ```
6. Now you can simply authenticate normal users via `guard('web')` and merchant users via `guard('merchant')`

**And for you register function**

```
public function register(Request $request)
{
    $guard = $request->user_type == 'user' ? 'web' : 'merchant';
    $user  = $this->create($request->all());

    auth()->guard($guard)->login($user);

    return redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

**You can use packages too...**

For example there's an awesome package: https://github.com/Sarav-S/Laravel-Multiauth

It will help you to handle all that hard stuff.

Comment: I almost do that, but now I have problem with getting guard in register function, any help in that function or if you could also edit that function...thank you

Comment: @epowah you should try to do something like this:

Comment: what should I do?

Comment: `$guard = $request->user_type == 'user' ? 'user' : 'merchant';`

`auth()->guard($guard)->login($user);`

Comment: I mean `$guard = $request->user_type == 'user' ? 'web' : 'merchant';`

Comment: i will try now, but why just don't you update that function in your answer?

Comment: Now it redirect me to my index view, but the header with login and register is still there. The menu in the header I'm checking with `Auth::guest()` any idea?

Comment: You should try to check with `Auth::guard($your_guard_by_user_type)->check()`

Comment: yes i understand, is some other way because that header I want to be for the two types of users

Comment: But anyway, is your first answer was answered?

Comment: Are you sure that your user was logged in? Maybe it is not working?

Comment: for normal user it works fine, it's not working for merchant, when i register new merchant it doesnt log in

Comment: I think that i find the mistake, i just add  guard merchant to 'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
        'guard' => 'merchant'
    ],

Comment: Maybe your Merchant model is not Based on User model?

Comment: Did you followed all my steps provided in my answer?

Comment: yes, see my last reply about `defaults` in `auth.php`...and also everything that is in User model I copied and put to merchant model, I only change the name of the model, you mean on that?

Comment: Not really, after i change the defaults and add the guard merchant, now it doesn't working for normal user

Comment: Oh, wait, you can't have two defaults on `guard`. You need to pick one default guard. For example `'guard' => 'web',`.

I think the problem is in this line:
`$guard = $request->user_type == 'user' ? 'web' : 'merchant';` 

You should try to dump the $guard variable to make sure it's correct.

Comment: let me try that, I will give you feedback

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129910/discussion-between-epowah-and-artur-subotkevic).

Answer (score 1):

First You need to set new `guard` at `auth.php`. And when login using `merchant` change the guard method so Laravel will look into merchant instead of users.

```
    if($request->user_type =='user'){
        $auth = auth()->guard();
    } else{
        $auth = auth()->guard('merchant');
    }

    $auth()->login($user);

    return redirect($this->redirectPath());
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication

Comment: Do I have to add only `guard` for merchant, or I have to add `guard`, `provider` and `password` in `auth.php` and where to put that function?

Comment: you need to setup providers, guards, and resetting password(if merchant can reset it) at auth.php

Comment: Yes I get it that, but can you modify the register function with this code. I'm new in laravel

Comment: Please see me updated register function in question, because it doesn't working again

Comment: `$this->create` won't get effect because it basically create new and you call another function.

for `auth()->login($user)` change to `$auth()->login($user)`. And my preference if you want to custom register method, why don't you create from scratch it alot easier.

Comment: If I delete `$this->create` it gives me user as a uninitialized variable, and I didn't start from scratch because I was thinking it would be easier with this...